# リビジョン比較がわかりづらい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 差分表示

編集前後の比較表示において、空白で区切られた単語単位に修正箇所が示されますが、日本語文章では単語を空白で区切ることをしないため、文が丸々修正単位となってしまいピンポイントの修正箇所が非常にわかりづらいです。

Stack Exchangeサイト共通のエンジン(？)を使用しているのなら日本語専用機能の実装は難しいのかも知れませんが、何とかならないものでしょうか。

[例：](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/501/revisions)

> [image: 左右2列]
>
> [image: 左右2列markdown]

Comment: いい指摘ですね！例文を編集で入れました。サイトにより、機能の一部が違うので、これは是非聞いてみます。スペースがある前提でシステムを作成しましたので、簡単にはできないと思いますが、編集が当サイトのモデルに非常に重要なんで、改善しましょう！

Comment: 2014/12/18現在「左右2列 markdown」ならば、純粋な該当箇所だけ差分ハイライトしてくれるようです。

Comment: @yohjp markdownの画面も入れました。同じ現象みたいです。

Comment: @jmac ありゃ。失礼しました。私のケースでは偶然そう見えただけのようです。

Comment: @yohjp スペースがある投稿、もしくはコードの編集なら多分そこまでひどくないですが、テキストなら、差が全く見えなくなります。

Comment: @jmac ありがとうございます！期待してます！

Comment: @ripple 現在のバグの中で、これは一番優先的だと思います。よく見つかりましたね！ずっと編集のレビューをしているのに、「訂正が多いな」が浮かばなかったですね。開発者に連絡をしましたので、解決を目指しましょう。

Comment: @yohjp 「左右2列 markdown」は日本語の句読点も区切りになってるぽいですね。

Comment: 参考までに私が編集した箇所→http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/1963/revisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

変更前：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

変更後：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: おおお素晴らしい。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 「左右2列 markdown」は以前のままのような・・・？仕様でしょうか？

Comment: @Ripple そう見たいですね。開発者に聞いてみます。

Comment: 大変遅くなりました。いつの間にか左右2列markdownもわかりやすくなっていました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

開発陣へのFYI: MeCab を使うことで日本語を分かち書きにすることができます。

```
$ echo "Web系などでよく使われるGitをUnityで使う際に気をつける点はなんでしょうか。" | mecab -Owakati 
Web 系 など で よく 使わ れる Git を Unity で 使う 際 に 気 を つける 点 は なん でしょ う か 。
```

[MeCab.NET](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/mecabdotnet/) というものもあるみたいです。